# Eliminate not a word from list

Tags: java, wordnet, jwi

Detecting actually not a word. To be clear with not a word, it has no meaning like leoepld. From list of word, can it be possible distinguish the word and not a word?

In Wordnet api, I have not seen any method to discriminate those words. I am not experienced much with Wordnet and JWI of mit.edu. Is it possible to do this thing told with those library and dictionary?

```
Example input;   Expected output
Set<String>      Set<String>

lodapke           looking    
asdfgre           university
looking           antonyms
university
antonyms
aeokalk
```

Programming language: Java, Platform: Windows, Library: wordnet & Jwi

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Hi George, I've edited your answer to change the tag back to Java. If your question is actually about using python and not java, then you should revert my edit, but also make it more clear where you want to use python in your code.

Comment: Do you mean unscrambling words to find any possible words that it can be? Hopefully you can be more clear, thanks.

Comment: Many years ago I wrote a tool (in REXX) to "smartly" lower-case the comments in PL/S code.  So as to not lower-case acronyms, the scheme used a dictionary of common acronyms, but also used an algorithm based on the number of contiguous consonants and a few other metrics.  Depending on how accurate you need to be you might be able to invent such a metric.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary file and check each of the words in your `Set<String>` against it.  If it doesn't appear in your dictionary file you can declare it as not a word.

You are not going to teach a program how to figure out for itself whether it is a word or not.